# iPhone 4S 64GB not charging unless switched off

Tags: iphone, battery, charging

My iPhone is simply not charging unless I switch it off while it is already plugged in. I suspect it to be a software problem, as when its off it charges. Windows does not seem to recognize the device but still charges when it is switched off.

I have tried cables that work on my friends phones and original cables, still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: What iOS version are you on?

Comment: I am on version 7.1.2

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not on iOS 8 yet? If not, then you should get it and then try charging. That could help you figure out whether or not it's a software problem.

Comment: Interestingly, [I'm having this problem, but not all the time](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/178395/23450). My phone charges at home, via a third-party cable and an Apple wall adapter. But nothing I've tried has resolved it not charging at work, even with a wall adapter – unless I turn the phone off first.

Comment: I tested the cables and wall adapter that weren't working for me (at one location) and I *think* the problem might be with *some* of the cables. I suspect that some circuitry in the cables might have been damaged and that's why I can only charge with them when the phone is off. When the phone is on, it's not able to validate or authorize the cables and thus refuses to draw power from them.

Comment: I have about 6 cables. None work, including the brand new on from my girlfriends original box. I am not too sure its a cable problem. It is very strange that a brand new cable with a charger that is still wrapped in its original plastic would not work. On my mac the phone is not even detected at all.

Comment: I took the phone to a cellphone repair shop and they sorted it out not for that much to be honest. He said he changed the charging dock or something for a pirate one. Works like a charm now. Thanks to all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Users complained that iPhone won't charge when it turns on. This is really strange. You can check by following methods:

- Check the USB cable
- Check the charging accessories
- Clean the charging port
- Hard-reset your iPhone
- Using iPhone Recovery Mode, restore the iPhone to factory settings

Answer (score 0):

dude its an IC problem which transfers power from the Dock to Mother board. Just go to some of the service store and change it. It may cost 800-900 Rs/-.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. We're looking for clear, helpful answers – could you be a little more thorough in yours? – from review